# Combine part of geojson object into another in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

**EDIT:** I am trying to manipulate JSON files in Python. In my data some polygons have multiple related information: coordinates (`LineString`) and **area percent** and **area** (`Text` and `Area` in `Point`), I want to combine them to a single JSON object. As an example, the data from files are as follows:

```
data = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "entities",
        "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F1"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [61.971069681118479, 36.504485105673659],
                        [46.471068755199667, 36.504485105673659],
                        [46.471068755199667, 35.954489281866685],
                        [44.371068755199758, 35.954489281866685],
                        [44.371068755199758, 36.10448936390457],
                        [43.371069617387093, 36.104489150107824],
                        [43.371069617387093, 23.904496401184584],
                        [48.172716774891342, 23.904496401184584],
                        [48.171892994728751, 17.404489374370311],
                        [61.17106949647404, 17.404489281863786],
                        [61.17106949647404, 19.404489281863786],
                        [61.971069689453991, 19.404489282256687],
                        [61.971069681118479, 36.504485105673659]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbMText",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F1",
                    "Text": "6%"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [49.745686139884583, 28.11445704760262, 0.0]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbMText",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F1",
                    "Area": "100"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [50.216857362443989, 63.981197759829229, 0.0]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F7"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [62.37106968111857, 36.504489398648715],
                        [62.371069689452725, 19.404489281863786],
                        [63.171069496474047, 19.404489281863786],
                        [63.171069496474047, 17.404489281863786],
                        [77.921070051947027, 17.404489281863786],
                        [77.921070051947027, 19.504489281855054],
                        [78.671070051947027, 19.504489281855054],
                        [78.671070051897914, 36.504485105717322],
                        [62.37106968111857, 36.504489398648715]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbMText",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F7",
                    "Text": "5.8%"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [67.27548061311245, 28.11445704760262, 0.0]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to combine `Point`'s `Text` and `Area` key and values to `LineString` based on `EntityHandle`'s values, and also delete  `Point` lines. The expected output is:

```
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "name": "entities",
        "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F1",
                    "Text": "6%",
                    "Area": "100"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [61.971069681118479, 36.504485105673659],
                        [46.471068755199667, 36.504485105673659],
                        [46.471068755199667, 35.954489281866685],
                        [44.371068755199758, 35.954489281866685],
                        [44.371068755199758, 36.10448936390457],
                        [43.371069617387093, 36.104489150107824],
                        [43.371069617387093, 23.904496401184584],
                        [48.172716774891342, 23.904496401184584],
                        [48.171892994728751, 17.404489374370311],
                        [61.17106949647404, 17.404489281863786],
                        [61.17106949647404, 19.404489281863786],
                        [61.971069689453991, 19.404489282256687],
                        [61.971069681118479, 36.504485105673659]
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "Layer": "0",
                    "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference",
                    "EntityHandle": "2F7",
                    "Text": "5.8%"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "LineString",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [62.37106968111857, 36.504489398648715],
                        [62.371069689452725, 19.404489281863786],
                        [63.171069496474047, 19.404489281863786],
                        [63.171069496474047, 17.404489281863786],
                        [77.921070051947027, 17.404489281863786],
                        [77.921070051947027, 19.504489281855054],
                        [78.671070051947027, 19.504489281855054],
                        [78.671070051897914, 36.504485105717322],
                        [62.37106968111857, 36.504489398648715]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is it possible to get result above in Python? Thanks.

**Updated solution**, thanks to @dodopy:

```
import json
features = data["features"]
point_handle_text = {
    i["properties"]["EntityHandle"]: i["properties"]["Text"]
    for i in features
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "Point"
}
point_handle_area = {
    i["properties"]["EntityHandle"]: i["properties"]["Area"]
    for i in features
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "Point"
}
combine_features = []
for i in features:
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "LineString":
        i["properties"]["Text"] = point_handle_text.get(i["properties"]["EntityHandle"])
        combine_features.append(i)
data["features"] = combine_features

combine_features = []
for i in features:
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "LineString":
        i["properties"]["Area"] = point_handle_area.get(i["properties"]["EntityHandle"])
        combine_features.append(i)
data["features"] = combine_features

with open('test.geojson', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-131-d132c8854a9c>", line 6, in <module>
    for i in features
  File "<ipython-input-131-d132c8854a9c>", line 7, in <dictcomp>
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "Point"
KeyError: 'Text'
```

Comment: So you would like to essentially delete the "Feature" section if a "LineString" section exists with the same "EntityHandle"?

Comment: Only delete `Point` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example like this:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(json_data)
features = data["features"]
point_handle_text = {
    i["properties"]["EntityHandle"]: i["properties"]["Text"]
    for i in features
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "Point"
}
combine_features = []
for i in features:
    if i["geometry"]["type"] == "LineString":
        i["properties"]["Text"] = point_handle_text.get(i["properties"]["EntityHandle"])
        combine_features.append(i)
data["features"] = combine_features
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Your method works perfectly, I have nothing to say but thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry, may I ask one more question, what if some `EntityHandle`, let's say `2F1`, besides `"Text": "6%"`, also has another point object `"Area": "100"`, how can combine them together `"properties": {"Layer": "0", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbMText", "EntityHandle": "2F1", "Text": "6%", "Area": 100}`

Comment: you can build an area dict like point_handle_text or add area as the mutiple value, then you can get the area value from dict while build combine_features

Comment: I updated my question and I'll try to solve the problem. ;)

Comment: I update the example JSON data, but I get a error, would you please check and tell me the reason to get this error?

Comment: because of some item does not have the key： Text，check like this，`if i["geometry"]["type"] == "Point" and i["properties"].get("Text")`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to get your result in python.  It just requires storing the json data into a data structure we can work with in python and then writing an algorithm to combine features with the same entity type. I wrote up a script to do just that, along with comments. The program extracts the text property from the `Point` feature and places it into the properties of the `LineString` feature. Then, we essentially discard `Point`.
BTW, your 'before' json data has a trailing comma that shouldn't be there.
Using Python 3.7.0:

```py
import json
import collections


def main():
    with open('before_data.json') as f:
        before_data = json.load(f)  # makes a python dict from the json file and stores in before
        features = before_data['features']  # list of features
        # loop through features, construct dictionary of entity handle mapped to point texts
        point_entities = collections.defaultdict()  # to avoid 'if key not in' pattern
        for feature in features:
            entity_handle = feature['properties']['EntityHandle']
            # only append points
            if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Point':
                point_entities[entity_handle] = feature['properties']['Text']
        merged_features = []
        for feature in features:
            if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'LineString':
                entity_handle = feature['properties']['EntityHandle']
                text_percent = point_entities[entity_handle]
                feature['properties']['Text'] = text_percent
                merged_features.append(feature)
        # print(json.dumps(before_data, indent=4))
        result = before_data
        result['features'] = merged_features
    # compare with your expected output
    with open('after_data.json') as f:
        after_data = json.load(f)
        print(result == after_data)  # returns True
    # finally, write your result to a file
    with open('result.json', 'w') as output_file:
        json.dump(result, output_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a error here: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<ipython-input-116-23aea5f1ef3b>", line 57, in <module> main() File "<ipython-input-116-23aea5f1ef3b>", line 32, in main point_feature = features[1] IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Did you run it on the same data from your question or on different data?

Comment: Different data but same structure, just more `LineString` and `Point`

Comment: In this different data, do you have entities with more than one pair of `LineString` and `Point` features?

Comment: Not all `LineString`s have correspondent `Point` features.

Comment: I see.  That's where my code messed up.  I made the assumption that every `LineString` would have a corresponding `Point`.  Next time you should include that important piece of information :).  I know that you got your solution, but I'll still update my solution to make it work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, please take this situation into account if you can: if some `EntityHandle`s, let's say `2F1`, besides `"Text": "6%"`, also has another point object `"Area": "100"`, how can combine them together `"properties": {"Layer": "0", "SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbMText", "EntityHandle": "2F1", "Text": "6%", "Area": 100}`, and at final `point` of  `Area` should be removed as `Text`.