# Merge number of polygons to multipolygon

Tags: python, json, geojson

I have a list with thousands of json polygon geometries that look like this:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883],[-3.7487037670057,48.1549328094763],[-3.74881026067484,48.1551269441743],[-3.7489842306003,48.1562730580435],[-3.74891349344581,48.1564591451586],[-3.74808156498281,48.1564431307103],[-3.74508499799638,48.1571063739741],[-3.74469509883265,48.1569830965023],[-3.74442860883604,48.156338388502],[-3.7456218240484,48.1559377887423],[-3.74765763078163,48.1556344996134],[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883]]]}
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883],[-3.7487037670057,48.1549328094763],[-3.74881026067484,48.1551269441743],[-3.7489842306003,48.1562730580435],[-3.74891349344581,48.1564591451586],[-3.74808156498281,48.1564431307103],[-3.74508499799638,48.1571063739741],[-3.74469509883265,48.1569830965023],[-3.74442860883604,48.156338388502],[-3.7456218240484,48.1559377887423],[-3.74765763078163,48.1556344996134],[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883]]]}
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883],[-3.7487037670057,48.1549328094763],[-3.74881026067484,48.1551269441743],[-3.7489842306003,48.1562730580435],[-3.74891349344581,48.1564591451586],[-3.74808156498281,48.1564431307103],[-3.74508499799638,48.1571063739741],[-3.74469509883265,48.1569830965023],[-3.74442860883604,48.156338388502],[-3.7456218240484,48.1559377887423],[-3.74765763078163,48.1556344996134],[-3.74761249275648,48.1553321393883]]]}
```

The result should look similar to this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 14.099648300117231, 10.223915592028142 ], [ 15.684642438452517, 10.49589683470106 ], [ 16.191090269636575, 7.447831184056278 ], [ 14.690504103165296, 7.419695193434941 ], [ 14.099648300117231, 10.223915592028142 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 17.841735052754977, 10.355216881594378 ], [ 21.030480656506445, 10.130128956623686 ], [ 19.454865181711604, 6.172332942555691 ], [ 17.597889800703395, 6.997655334114894 ], [ 17.841735052754977, 10.355216881594378 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I want to combine always 50 rows to multipolygons.
I think I have to do something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55412100/10437064, but I don't know how to get acess to the "type" and "coordinates" without having "features" and "geometry".

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result? How do you want to combine them?

Comment: In the end, one multipolygon should consist of 50 polygons. Therefore I have to merge 50 rows to one multipolygon. I would like to have every Multipolygon as a single geojson file.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: I do not have a complete code yet. I am not sure how I can reformat the geojson and therefore would be happy about a hint on how to solve the problem in the most efficient way. Sorry for not providing any code yet.